# Is there a CakePHP offline manual

Tags: cakephp, offline, manual

There used to be, but there don't seem to be any direct links. A little digging around revealed some answers which I thought it would be useful to share.

These are links to the manual in one page - useful for offline
use or creating a PDF using Dardo Sordi Bogado's build script.

1.2 Manual in one page
https://web.archive.org/web/20120730003805/http://book.cakephp.org/complete/3/The-Manual

1.3 Manual in one page
https://web.archive.org/web/20120730004040/http://book.cakephp.org/complete/876/The-Manual

Comment: As answered, there is now a direct link to download each manual from the website itself, so the question should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 'right' answer to my question, but the discussion has proved to be very useful.

As CakePHP now publish 'offline-able' manuals on their website for 2.x http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html this thread is effectively redundant.

Answer (score 9):

[GOOGLE DOCS -  CakePHP 1.3 Manual](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0ByNCj4MHL2TRZTY4N2NhZDQtOGQ5Mi00NGI1LTg1YzktNDI5MjdiN2YyYTRh&hl=en)

Answer (score 4):

You can download CakePHP's manual from their website:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/

In the welcome section you will find two download links :

Download the documentation:

```
epub format = http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/_downloads/en/CakePHPCookbook.epub
original source = https://github.com/cakephp/docs
```

Answer (score 2):

take my work: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cakephp-doc/files/

Answer (score 1):

I've used [gotAPI](http://www.gotapi.com/cake) in the past but it doesn't work if the API goes offline and doesn't cover the Cookbook.

I usually just refer people to the "All in one page" Cookbook links you mentioned as these can be saved as HTML or printed to PDF.

The main issue I've heard in the past about offline copies of the Cookbook is that the content is copyrighted to the [CSF](http://cakefoundation.org/), but - looking now - the content seems to be licensed for non-commercial sharing under a [creative commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/) license. ([IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL) though.)

Comment: The only real issue is currency. It's not a good idea to wholly rely on a static copy of an online manual. I'm not advocating any form of sharing of the manual and I'm sure this would rightly be frowned upon by CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

cakephp 1.3 offline docs as a zipped, google ads stripped off html http://www.4shared.com/zip/QbLIpxwC/Cake13_-html_docs.html .

Answer (score 0):

For learning Basic Cakephp 2.X version offline

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/_downloads/en/CakePHPCookbook.pdf

and For Advance CakePHP Tips on coding side you can download a manual from below link

http://www.pseudocoder.com/Super_Awesome_Advanced_CakePHP_Tips.pdf

i hope it will give you best guideline in CakePHP