# Download cakephp manual

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

From where I could download manual of cakephp 1.3 .......?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading a manual is strongly discouraged because it is alive in the same way that development is and subject to improvement and change. I recognise,however, the need for an offline copy and you can find instructions on where to look and how to build your own PDF copy here: [Is there a CakePHP offline manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044536/is-there-a-cakephp-offline-manual)

It's pretty straightforward. The cake links point to all-in-one-page versions which are useful in their own right for faster searching using **ctrl-f**

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/876/The-Manual). Can be found on book.cakephp.org

Edit: Removed link!